# Navagrahas with their consorts

Tags: temple, navagraha

In most of the temples of Karnataka, the Navagrahas are present with their consorts. In contrast at other places in India, only the Navagraha are there - without their consorts. Why is there such a significant difference? Please provide scriptural sources. Mythological explanations are also acceptable.